# GNU make + GCC: Let Makefile auto-generating dependencies for auto-generated files from static pattern rule

Tags: makefile

In a `Makefile` for GNU make, the dependencies are generated and used as follows.  This is a method I found at [mad-scientist.net](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/) and that works really well (for the complete Makefile see end of this question):

**1. Specify the modules:**

```
MODULES := main bar
```

**2. Add the magic from mad-scientist:**

```
DEPDIR := .deps
DEPFLAGS = -MT $@ -MMD -MP -MF $(DEPDIR)/$*.d

$(DEPDIR): ; @mkdir -p $@

DEPFILES := $(SRCS:%.c=$(DEPDIR)/%.d)
$(DEPFILES):

include $(wildcard $(DEPFILES))
```

**3. Use `DEPDIR` and `DEPFLAGS` in rules for objects and executables:**

```
main.x: $(OBJS)
    gcc $(OBJS) -o $@ -lm

%.obj: %.c
%.obj: %.c $(DEPDIR)/%.d | $(DEPDIR)
    gcc -c $< -O2 -o $@ $(DEPFLAGS)
```

Now I have the case that some of the files are auto-generated (copied from elsewhere in the example), like `bar.c` that's generated from `orig-bar.c`; similar for `bar.h`. This is done using a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern):

```py
GEN_SRC := bar.c bar.h

$(GEN_SRC): % : orig-%
    cp $< $@
```

and with that addition, the dependencies are incomplete and I am getting build fails due to non-existing files, e.g. `make` tries to build `main.obj` before generating `bar.h`, but `main.c` includes that header.

I could add all the dependencies by hand, like `bar.obj: bar.h` and `main.obj: bar.h`, but I'd like to avoid that and also use auto dependency generation.

**Question:** Is there a way so that the rules are applied in correct order, for example that `bar.h` is generated before `main.c` is compiled?

---

### File contents:

```cpp
> head main.c orig-bar.[ch]

==> main.c <==
#include <stdio.h>
#include "bar.h"

int main (void)
{
    printf ("Hallo main.\n");
    return 0;
}

==> orig-bar.c <==
#include "bar.h"

==> orig-bar.h <==
/* empty */
```

### Makefile

```bash
.SECONDARY: # Don't auto-delete intermediate files.

MODULES := main bar

all: main.x

.PHONY: all clean clean-all

###########################################################################
# http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/

SRCS := $(MODULES:%=%.c)
OBJS := $(SRCS:%.c=%.obj)

DEPDIR := .deps
DEPFLAGS = -MT $@ -MMD -MP -MF $(DEPDIR)/$*.d

$(DEPDIR): ; @mkdir -p $@

DEPFILES := $(SRCS:%.c=$(DEPDIR)/%.d)
$(DEPFILES):

include $(wildcard $(DEPFILES))
#############################################################

# Auto-generate some files.
GEN_SRC := bar.c bar.h

$(GEN_SRC): % : orig-%
    cp $< $@

#############################################################

EXTRA_DEP = Makefile

main.x: $(OBJS) $(EXTRA_DEP)
    gcc $(OBJS) -o $@ -lm

%.obj: %.c
%.obj: %.c $(EXTRA_DEP) $(DEPDIR)/%.d | $(DEPDIR)
    gcc -c $< -O2 -o $@ $(DEPFLAGS)

###########################################################

clean:
    rm -f $(wildcard *.x $(OBJS))

clean-all: clean
    rm -rf $(DEPDIR) $(wildcard $(GEN_SRC))
```

Comment: The short answer is "no" there's no straightforward way to do this.  I can imagine something complex where you map the source files to makefile included files somehow so that as part of the makefile rebuild step (you don't have one here if you use the advanced method) the source files are rebuilt, then maybe it would work.

Comment: @MadScientist: My impression is that the problem is with gcc, or how it is used: It compiles **and** tries to determine prerequisites. If there was a mode such that `#include "bar.h"` would not lead to an error, but to output an according dependency with `-M -fsyntax-only` or so?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is unfortunate.
It's the same as the problem you get when you auto-generate a `version.h`.
The slightly sub-optimal version is to generate `version.h` (or in your case any of your headers) before compiling *any* source.

A sketch:

```
auto-gen-headers := $(filter-out %.c,${GEN_SRC})
${OBJS}: | ${auto-gen-headers}
```

Comment: I tried it. When I `make clean-all`, then `make` it works. When I then `rm bar.h` and remake, it says *"nothing to do"* when I expect to rebuild `bar.h` and then `main.obj` again?

Comment: `make -d` will tell you what _make_ is looking for. Are you sure `bar.h` is included in `$auto-gen-headers`?

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: Is there a way so that the rules are applied in correct order, for example that `bar.h` is generated before `main.c` is compiled?

You need to declare the generated headers as prerequisites of the objects that depend on them.  That is *the* way to control the order in which `make` applies rules.

You can bite the bullet and just write the needed dependency rules explicitly.  The main issue here is doing the job correctly and keeping the result up to date, but I don't think it would be too hard to create a tool to automate that -- just not as an (efficient) part of ordinary builds.

You can get the prerequisites you need fairly cleanly at the cost of sometimes performing unneeded rebuilds of object files.  Making *all* the generated headers be prerequisites of *all* the object files will accomplish that.

You can do it fairly cleanly and avoid unnecessary rebuilds at the cost of opening yourself to build failures in certain uncommon situations. Making *all* the generated headers be **order-only** prerequisites of *all* the object files, and additionally making then regular prerequisites of the overall executable(s) will accomplish that.  This relies on the fact that the auto-generated depfiles will upgrade the order-only pereqs to regular ones where appropriate.  Something like this:

```
main.x: $(OBJS) $(GEN_SRC)
    gcc $(OBJS) -o $@ -lm

%.obj: %.c
%.obj: %.c $(DEPDIR)/%.d | $(DEPDIR) $(filter %.h,$(GEN_SRC))
    gcc -c $< -O2 -o $@ $(DEPFLAGS)
```

It works like so:

- having the generated files as regular prerequisites of the main target ensures that they do get built, at least when the main target is being built;
- having the headers as order-only prerequisites of the object files ensures that if they need to be (re)built then that will happen before any attempt to build any of the object files, even when no dependency information has yet been generated, but does not cause the object files to be rebuilt on account of being out-of-date with respect to the generated headers.
- when auto-generated dependency information is available, it will upgrade the generated headers to ordinary prerequisites of those objects that genuinely depend on them.

That will break, however, if you ask `make` directly to build one of the object files when the auto-generated dependency information is unavailable, and perhaps in other uncommon situations as well.

Comment: close but no cigar, now they depend on .d's that dont have a recipe... just have the recipe build the .d's with the proper DEPFLAG, and then just have failable line that includes the dep files. ( i.e. just need a '-' in front of the include for his dep files)